# Add WCF service as link from website project to webapplication project

Tags: wcf

In my solution I have a "website" project and "WebApplication" project. In the website project I have a WCF service under folder called Services. So by default it places MyService.cs file under App_Code folder.

Now I am trying to add this same WCF service **as link** file into my WebApplication project. But as the [.svc & .cs] are in two different location in website project it is not being picked up as a service in WebApplication project.

Any solution to this problem ? Any thoughts or ideas ?

Thanks in advance,
Keyrav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to totally separate out the WCF service into its own class-library assembly (no code in the *.svc.cs code-behind or the `App_code` directory), and then reference that WCF service assembly from your different projects and web sites.